# Конфликт двух форм

Tags: activerecord, php, yii

Всем доброго времени суток. У меня появилась проблема, создал на днях виджет

```
class SearchWidget extends CWidget {

    public function run() {
        $model = new Sites('find');

        if (isset($_POST['Sites'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['Sites'];

            if ($model->validate()) {
                if (Sites::model()->exists('url=:url', array(':url' => $model->url))) {
                    $this->controller->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('site/search', array('url' => $model->url)));
                } else {
                    $dom = new DOMDocument();
                    @$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($model->url));

                    $model->name = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;
                    $model->desc = 'Описание сайта';
                    $model->active = 0;
                    if($model->save())
                        $this->controller->redirect(Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('sites/view', array('id' => $model->id)));

                }
            }
        }

        $this->render('_searchbox', array(
            'model' => $model
        ));
    }

}
```

Прдеставление _searchbox

```
<div class="form">
    <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm'); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'url'); ?>

        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Найти'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'url'); ?>
    </div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

Разместил его на сайте, вроде всё норма, всё работает, но тут мне нужно было добавить форму добавления сайта в каталог(та же модель)

```
public function actionAdd() {
        $model = new Sites('add');

        if (isset($_POST['Sites'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['Sites'];

            if ($model->save()) {
                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('payment/index', array('id' => $paymentModel->id)));
            }
        }

        $this->render('add', array('model' => $model));
    }
```

Представление

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm'); ?>

    <?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('success')): ?>
    <div class = 'flash-success'>
        <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('success'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'url'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'url'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'url'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'category_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'category_id', 
            CHtml::listData(Category::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name')
        ); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'desc'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'desc', array('cols'=>40, 'rows'=>8, 'style'=>'resize: none;')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'desc'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Добавить'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Виджет  отображатеся в layout'e и должен быть доступен в любой страницы сайта. Но вот незадача, когда я захожу на страницу добавления сайта, и нажимаю кнопку, валидация проходит сразу 2-х форм 0_о вверхняя(поиск), и на добавление. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему, и что с эти можно сделать((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя в двух местах проверяется

```
if (isset($_POST['Sites'])) {
```

дай формам разные имена, например "Search" и "Sites"

Comment: Имена или ID?

Comment: Всё, я всё понял, спасибо, проблема решена :)